# Quantifying the impact of offering alternative signup/login methods?

Tags: login, authentication, metrics, quantitative-analysis, signup

Nowadays it's common for websites to offer signup/signin methods that don't require making an account (email/password) for that specific site, for example 'Login with x':

- Facebook
- Google
- Twitter
- LinkedIn
- etc

By how much does offering each common alternative signup method increase the signup rate for an average website, as opposed to just offering traditional email/password signup?

Notes:

- Obviously these statistics could differ (a lot) from site to site, depending on the demographic and other factors. But I currently have very little idea of how much impact each signup method has, so *any* information is a massive improvement on that
- Very interested to know if any studies have been conducted, or if any companies (big or small) have released statistics.

#### Example

Suppose a website only offered the traditional username/password signup method and it signed up 1% of the visitors to the site, but then it got a 'Login with Google' feature, and its signup rate went to 1.1%, then we could very roughly guess the 'Login with Google' feature increased the signup rate by 10%. (figures completely made up)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't have normally responded on this, but you said "any information is a massive improvement."  While I can't speak to signup conversion rates, I can speak to an angle which you may not have thought of which, for me, adds a bit of trust to a name I haven't heard of, especially in a time of information/password leaks.

Security and familiarity.  People know Facebook/Google/Twitter, etc.  If a user signs up through those services, their benefit is two-fold.  1.) They can see or strip your access to their information at any time (using a familiar interface on that provider).  2.) You don't have any of their actual password information.  If there is a data breach on your site, they don't have to change a bunch of passwords, if they are reusing them (even though they shouldn't be) in multiple places.

The case for multiple services can be made in that each one includes a larger portion of the population.  Some people are anti-google/facebook, or might not have a twitter account (hard to believe, I know).  It stands to reason, then, that multiple options increases the rate (though, I can't speak to how much).  There is also a UX case to be made against providing too many options and overloading the user, however.

I know this doesn't answer the need-for-numbers part of your question, but I hope it helps.